# Firefox shows all background color as white starting today on all pages

Tags: firefox

When I started Firefox today all background colors were gone as in the following screenshot:

[image]

This probably happened because I have set up automatic software updates, so something must have gotten broken.

What I've tried to no avail:

- start Firefox with `--safe-mode` to disable all plugins
- rested GNOME color themes to Ubuntu's default
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. This upgraded from Firefox 36 to 37.

Comment: yes if I'm not mistaken this could happen in vers. 36 and before indeed in 37 it's gone and I mean it's gone because I could reproduce your issue easy by going to edit/preferences/content there if you allow to use system color or untick allowing fonts to load their fonts for pages it will turn it white as on your screenshot and it depends on system theme schema call it a bug or whatever but this issue seems to disappear in vers. 37.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a "Firefox refresh", which seems to be a way to import old settings into a new version of Firefox. To do it go:

```
Menu > Help > Troubleshooting information > Refresh Firefox
```

I suspect that the break was linked to:

- having the color toggle plugin installed https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/color-toggle/ (which for now is broken in Firefox 37)
- having Firefox sync setup between work and home. My work computer had recently upgraded to 37.

If someone understands better, please edit this answer.